# How do I print a variable value in QMessageBox?

Tags: c++, qt, messagebox, qmessagebox

Do I need to use a `QString` first then put it in the msgbox? Are there any examples?

Comment: Does QString have formatting methods?  You could use `sprintf` or `std::stringstream` and then pass that to `QString`.

Comment: Reminder:  Have you clicked the green check mark on all the answers you have accepted for the questions you asked?

Answer (score 2):

The [QMessageBox](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qmessagebox.html) documentation has examples in it:

```
QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setText("Put your text here");
msgBox.exec();
```

There are a few others in there. Please read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the folowing example and you can add as many as arguments you want.

```
int device_count=0;
QString status = QString("Found %1 device(s):").arg(device_count);
QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Info"), status);
```